# How can I get the full URL of file uploaded to s3 with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this to upload pictures to one `bucket` on `s3` in `AWS`

```
$image = $picture;
$ext = explode(";", explode("/",explode(",", $image)[0])[1])[0];
$image = str_replace('data:image/'.$ext.';base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = str_random(10) . '.' . $ext;
$fullImagePath = 'datasheets/' . $imageName;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullImagePath, base64_decode($image));

$DataSheetPicture = new DataSheetPicture();
$DataSheetPicture->data_sheet_id = $DataSheet->id;
$DataSheetPicture->picture = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullImagePath);
$DataSheetPicture->save();
```

The above code works fine, it uploads the pictures successfully to the `bucket`, but on this line

```
$DataSheetPicture->picture = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullImagePath);
```

It saves the URL in the database like these

> /datasheets/6GcfzgUPrA.jpeg
>   /datasheets/AuqHmu8p0W.jpeg

But I need get the URL like this

> https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/FULL-IMAGE-PATH

I don't want to concatenate the region or the bucket name because it could be dynamic

Answer (score 4):

The following will give you the proper URL:

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
```

Since `Laravel 5.2` you're also able to use `cloud()`

```
return Storage::cloud()->url($filename);
```

> I don't want to concatenate the region or the bucket name because it could be dynamic

Then you must be modifying your config and not doing this manually to work correctly, for example:

```
config([
    'filesystem.disks.s3.bucket'   => 'my_bucket',
    'filesystem.disks.s3.region'   => 'my_region'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `AWS_URL` setting from your `.env` file, the `Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullImagePath)` should give you the proper URL that you need

See discussion also here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storage-url-from-s3?page=1&replyId=482913